# Drop the required surrounding quotes in the lexer/parser

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I several projects I have run into a similar effect in my grammars.

I have the need to parse something like `Key="Value"`

So I create a grammar (simplest I could make to show the effect):

```
grammar test;

KEY   : [a-zA-Z0-9]+ ;
VALUE : DOUBLEQUOTE [ _a-zA-Z0-9.-]+ DOUBLEQUOTE ;

DOUBLEQUOTE     : '"'           ;
EQUALS          : '='           ;

entry    : key=KEY EQUALS value=VALUE;
```

I can now parse `thing="One Two Three"` and in my code I receive

- `key` = `thing`
- `value` = `"One Two Three"`

In all of my projects I end up with an extra step to strip those `"` from the value.

Usually something like this (I use Java)

```java
String value = ctx.value.getText();
value = value.substring(1, value.length()-1);
```

In my real grammars I find it very hard to move the check of the surrounding `"` into the parser.

Is there a clean way to already drop the `"` by doing something in the lexer/parser?

Essentially I want `ctx.value.getText()` to return `One Two Three` instead of `"One Two Three"`.

---

Update:

I have been playing with the excellent answer provided by Bart Kiers and found this variation which does exactly what I was looking for.
By putting the DOUBLEQUOTE on a hidden channel they are used by the lexer and hidden from the parser.

TestLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

KEY         : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
DOUBLEQUOTE : '"' -> channel(HIDDEN), pushMode(STRING_MODE);
EQUALS      : '=';

mode STRING_MODE;

  STRING_DOUBLEQUOTE
   : '"' -> channel(HIDDEN), type(DOUBLEQUOTE), popMode
   ;

  STRING
   : [ _a-zA-Z0-9.-]+
   ;
```

and

TestParser.g4

```
parser grammar TestParser;

options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

entry : key=KEY EQUALS value=STRING ;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice trick to put the quotes on the `HIDDEN` channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
VALUE
 : DOUBLEQUOTE [ _a-zA-Z0-9.-]+ DOUBLEQUOTE 
   {setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1));}
 ;
```

Needless to say: this ties your grammar to Java, and (depending how many embedded Java code you have) your grammar will be hard to port to some other target language.

#### EDIT

Once a token is created, there is no built-in way to separate it (other than doing so in embedded actions, as I demonstrated). What you're looking for *can* be done, but that means rewriting your grammar so that a string literal is not constructed as a single token. This can be done by using [lexical modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes) so that the string can be constructed in the parser.

A quick demo:

##### TestLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

KEY         : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
DOUBLEQUOTE : '"' -> pushMode(STRING_MODE);
EQUALS      : '=';

mode STRING_MODE;

  STRING_DOUBLEQUOTE
   : '"' -> type(DOUBLEQUOTE), popMode
   ;

  STRING_ATOM
   : [ _a-zA-Z0-9.-]
   ;
```

##### TestParser.g4

```
parser grammar TestParser;

options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

entry : key=KEY EQUALS value;

value : DOUBLEQUOTE string_atoms DOUBLEQUOTE;

string_atoms : STRING_ATOM*;
```

If you now run the Java code:

```java
Lexer lexer = new TestLexer(CharStreams.fromString("Key=\"One Two Three\""));
TestParser parser = new TestParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

TestParser.EntryContext entry = parser.entry();
System.out.println(entry.value().string_atoms().getText());
```

this will be printed:

```
One Two Three
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping for a cleaner solution. I just now found this which seems to be a closely related (unfortunately closed) request: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1170

Comment: No problem. Of course, you could move the code in a (static) class, but you'd still need the embed target code inside `{ ... }` for this to work. There is no other way.

Comment: @NielsBasjes also checkout my **EDIT**

Comment: I see you have split the lexer and parser into separate files. I that simply your preferred way of doing this or is this a requirement to be able to do this?

Comment: Yes, this works very nice! Thanks.

Comment: "that simply your preferred way of doing this", I prefer this when the grammars get large, but in this case, using lexical modes, you have to do it.